# Conditionally adapt listbox items WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I want to fill a listbox based on user-input. The user input is an array of strings, where I examine each string. I process the string (for example correct any typos) and put the string as an item in the listbox. I want to color the item to indicate if I understand the input or not. I have 4 conditions and so 4 colors.

I managed to get the desired text in the listbox, but so far I didn't find the solution how to do the coloring.

This is the part of the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="QuickSlide_2._0.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:QuickSlide_2._0"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="True" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="DarkGray" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MinHeight="720" MinWidth="1280" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <c:coll_items x:Key="item"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    --------

    <ListBox Height="468" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="789,144,0,0" Name="output" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" ItemsSource="{StaticResource item}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=item_text}" Background="{Binding Path=background_color}" Width="440" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListBox>

    ----------
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the part of the c# code for building the listbox:

```
public class item
{
    public string item_text {get; set;}
    public SolidColorBrush background_color {get; set;}

    public item(String item_text, SolidColorBrush background_color)
    {
        this.item_text = item_text;
        this.background_color = background_color;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<item> coll_items;

    private void Check_input_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        private string[] split_input;
        private string[,] Results;
        // Split the input from richtextbox into a string[] array

        TextRange textrange = new TextRange(input_dump.Document.ContentStart, input_dump.Document.ContentEnd);

        split_input = textrange.Text.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Validate the input
        Results = InputEngine.check_input(split_input);

        // The first column in results holds the string, the second holds the status
        // Add the results to the listbox
        for (int i = 0; i < Results.Length / 7; i++)
        {
            if ( Results[i,1] == 1)
            {              
                coll_items.Add(new item(Results[i,0],new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)));
            }
            else if ( Results[i,1] == 2)      
            {              
                coll_items.Add(new item(Results[i,0],new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)));
            }  
            else if ( Results[i,1] == 3)      
            {              
                coll_items.Add(new item(Results[i,0],new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
            }        
            else
            {
                coll_items.Add(new item(Results[i,0],new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)));
            }
        }
        this.DataContext = this;

       ----------

    }
```

I have several years of (night-time) programming experience but WPF is pretty new. I probably make a very obvious mistake, but please help me find it.

Comment: Instead of binding the background, you can use DataTriggers instead. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you tell us if you're getting any binding errors in the output window? Ensure before you run the application that Tools/Options/Debugging/Output Window has the Data Binding set to Warning.

Comment: @failedprogramming Most sources I've encountered generally warn against DataTriggers, given that they're 1. an implementation of business logic in the view, and 2. much more difficult to test than binding to objects in code-behind/the view model.

Comment: On a side note, It's not a good idea to expose fields of a class. Use properties instead.

Comment: Background colours should be managed in your view and not your business model. Your business logic should reflect the "condition" or status and you would bind the data trigger to this condition property. E.g. if the color red is for an error status, your business logic should be able to know if the current status/condition is error. How and what colour to use in a view is none of its business.

Comment: For your case, look at the answer by @Aphex rather than the accepted answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: @failedprogramming I don't disagree with that, necessarily, but I think you're better suited in most cases using a converter to move between the condition and the color.

Comment: @furkle i agree converters would be great in this situation where we are only changing the background color based on a property. But it might be a lot easier to use a data trigger instead of converters if you had to toggle multiple things or deal with animation. Bottom line is neither data triggers nor converters are always the best solution in every situation. I just wanted to point out that your opinion that data triggers is business logic isn't quite right IMO.

Comment: That's a totally fair point - I have a probably unfair bias against DataTriggers, mostly because I freak out if I'm not able to do step-throughs.